# linq to sql custom method using Expression<Func<...>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

Maybe I am making myself somewhat difficult in this issue. The goal is to use an object (here `SearchForm`) to analyze the database records and returns if the record matches the search entry.

Since my website allows an advanced search form, the `SearchForm` object contains a lot properties (5 input fields, some dropdown lists, and a lot checkboxes).
I am using

- C# NET 4.0 (not higher due of web host)
- LINQ-to-SQL
- ASP.NET MVC 4

Here is my snippet so far:

```
public static IEnumerable<CarDetails> SearchByForm(SearchForm form) {
    // get db instance
    _db = new MyDBDataContext();
    var q = from Cars_car c in _db.Cars_cars
    join Cars_equipment e in _db.Cars_equipments on c.equipmentId equals e.id
    where ValidData.Invoke(c, form)
    select new CarDetails {
         // filling CarDetails data
    };
    return q;
}
```

And the `ValidData` method is an `Expression<Func<...>` type.

```
private static Expression<Func<Cars_car, SearchForm, bool>> ValidData = (c, f) => MatchesSearchData(f, c);
```

where `MatchesSearchData` is the method behind to validate each records

```
private static bool MatchesSearchData(SearchForm f, Cars_car c) {
    // long check if true or false and returns it
}
```

But there is an error, `the overloaded method has some invalid arguments` at `ValidData.Invoke(c, form)`.

**Am I making myself difficult, or is this the good way to accomplish my results?
If so, can someone provide me a solution to the above error note?
If not, some guidance to use other way to solve this?**

There is a way to do this with stored procedures, true, but I rather prefer to do this at this layer.

Used sources;

- [article about custom LINQ to SQL method](http://www.flexlabs.org/2010/01/extending-linq-selectors-with-custom-expressions)
- [blog post calling custom methods](http://www.atrevido.net/blog/2007/09/05/Calling+Custom+Methods+In+LINQtoSQL.aspx)
- [other blog post about same subject](http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx/)

**EDIT 1**

An answer from user Erti-Chris Eelmaa has solved the compiler error by using `Compile()`-method.

```
    where ValidData.Compile().Invoke(c, form)
```

But when running, it redirects me to the error page. Apparently, i am getting `method has no supported translation to sql` error.

In Controllers,

```
public ActionResult Results(SearchForm form) {
    ViewBag.cars = Cars_car.SearchByForm(form);
    return View("Results");
}
```

and on template (just quick testing)

```
@foreach (var car in ViewBag.cars)** {
<p>results : car.Make !</p>
}
```

** Here, an `method Boolean Invoke(MVCproject2.Models.Cars_car, MVCproject2.Models.SearchForm) has no supported translation to sql` error got thrown.  That's weird, because that Expression method was added to provide a custom method to LINQ to SQL.

Or am i wrong ?

Comment: Please don't put answers inside the question. They are meant to be posted below, as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want method to be part of the SQL query, you need to create your method on SQL server, and then call it. Like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReverseCustName(@string varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @custName varchar(100)
    -- Implementation left as exercise for users.
    RETURN @custName
END

// and C# part

[Function(Name = "dbo.ReverseCustName", IsComposable = true)]
[return: Parameter(DbType = "VarChar(100)")]
public string ReverseCustName([Parameter(Name = "string",
    DbType = "VarChar(100)")] string @string)
{
    return ((string)(this.ExecuteMethodCall(this,
        ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())),
        @string).ReturnValue));
}
```

You can now use ReverseCustName(string) in your "SQL" query.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386973(v=vs.100).aspx

Alternatively you can download everything in to your C# client and execute `Where` there.

```
public static IEnumerable<CarDetails> SearchByForm(SearchForm form) {
    Func<RetailCar_car, SearchForm> compiledLambda = ValidData.Compile();
    // get db instance
    _db = new MyDBDataContext();
    var q = (from Cars_car c in _db.Cars_cars
    join Cars_equipment e in _db.Cars_equipments on c.equipmentId equals e.id)
    .ToList()
    .Where(x => compiledLambda(c, form))
    .Select(x => new CarDetails {});

    return q;
}
```

Let's get this straight:when you are using `DbContext`, you're using `IQueryable`. The class is meant to generate SQL queries. If you combine your C# method with IQueryable, LINQSQL doesn't know how to translate it to SQL query.

Those two solutions correspond to: either create new SQL method in SQL server, or download everything to C# side using `ToList()`, which means that `IQueryable` will be switched to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: i got the `Invoke()` method from a blog post. ( [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355170%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) )
Your solution has returned with no compiling errors, but with `has no supported translation to SQL` at the template (going to edit post).

Comment: wow ! you gave me a super assist ! (if you know football). I had to adapt the code a bit, but now it works as expected. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm whether the following LINQ is correct

```
var q = from Cars_car c in _db.Cars_cars
    join Cars_equipment e in _db.Cars_equipments on c.equipmentId equals e.id
```

I can't understand why you are using alias to alias here. According to me, this snippet should be like

```
var q = from c in _db.Cars_cars
        join e in _db.Cars_equipments on c.equipmentId equals e.id
```

May be this is not the reason for the error, but I wanted to confirm if my understanding is correct.

Comment: it's same. It doesn't matter, but i am doing this way to improve code readability.